# Ruby: Execute code for every subclass

Tags: ruby, inheritance, metaprogramming, subclass

Given a parent class is there a way to insert code for every subclass on load? ie.

Given: `ParentClass`, how do I insert code like so:

```
class ChildClass < ParentClass
   execute_function

   ...
end
```

for all child classes of `ParentClass`?

Comment: What if those classes are already loaded? What should this code do?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Err, how can a class be loaded if its parent isn't loaded?

Comment: @meagar: it's late night and I'm asking silly questions :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the `ParentClass` override the inherited method

```
class ParentClass
   def self.inherited(subclass)
      execute_function
      super
   end
   ...
end
```

See: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited

Comment: wow... spent so much time looking for this. it would be correct to use `super(subclass)` for safety correct?

Comment: You could but it's not required. `super` with no arguments will call the the method in the parent class with the same name using the same arguments.

Comment: Russ Olsen has an interesting example of the use of this hook in his book, Eloquent Ruby. Each child class reads a different type of file, and the parent class is structured in such a way that no changes are needed to it when a new child class is added.  Re super, that's of course only needed when you want ParentClass' parent to be informed as well.

Comment: However the subclass that you get here will not be complete. For example if you define a class method or class constant in the subclass it will not be available here.

Comment: @trcarden, how could one execute code only after the subclass has been read?